# Sveltekit / mdsvex - Importing markdown file and getting length

Tags: typescript, svelte, sveltekit

In +page.ts I have the following code:

```
export const prerender = "auto";

export async function load({ params }) {
  const post = await import(`../md-files/${params.slug}.md`)
  const content = post.default

  return {
    content,
  }
}
```

I would like to get the length of the text in the markdown file. But both post.length and content.length are undefined. How do I get the length of the text?

Answer (score 3):

So underlying you have Vite which takes care of this. So my guess is, but I have not tried myself, that you have to add '?raw' to the path.

Here is the documentation that gave me that idea:

https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets.html#importing-asset-as-string

Comment: thank you, it saved me some amount of stress and probably a job :)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
const content = post.default.render()
const length = content.length
```

Comment: I get the error "TypeError: post.default.render is not a function". Without .render() I get length as 1.

Comment: @Wessi I was using `import.meta.glob` rather than straight import and got up and running from this article: https://joshcollinsworth.com/blog/build-static-sveltekit-markdown-blog